# Does debugging a netfilter service in windows belong to kernel debug?

Tags: windows, ndis

I know that to do kernel debug I need 2 OS,the hosting OS and the target OS.

but does a netfilter service(ndis filter,to be exact) belong to the kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. NDIS filters are loaded into kernel mode. There is an almost identical question already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742177). Kernel debugging techniques have to be applied.